# split an existing iOS app project into static library and app skin project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I would like to split an existing iOS app project into one static library and one app project.

Since the existing app project has been copies multiple times into brand new instances with different resources(graphics, icons etc) and settings.

I find it's hard to maintain across difference instances once the core project has been updated.

So i'm turning the core project into a static library with model, views and third party libraries.

the other project contains the app part which only contains customised resources and app settings.

the problem is how can the classes in the static library getting the app settings from the app project and the main app project calling classes in the library.

any good practise and tools for that?

Answer (score 1):

The main app project can make use of your static library classes through exported header (.h) files. I would recommend reading a bit about them here:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/iOSStaticLibraries/Articles/creating.html

And creating the static library here:

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

**As for** providing the app-specific settings to your static library, it sounds like your static library might need to contain a `ApplicationSettings` protocol or similar, that can be provided to the static library for any calls that require it. Your protocol could define getters/setters for any known properties your application possesses.

```
@protocol ApplicationSettings

- (BOOL)isUserReallyAwesome;
- (void)setIsUserReallyAwesome:(BOOL)awesome;

@end
```

Then you can either configure an instance of this object statically, or you can provide to each static library method that requires it:

```
- (void)someStaticLibraryMethodWithArg:(NSString *)arg settings:(id<ApplicationSettings>)settings { ... }
```

Comment: that's a good idea with the applicationSettings. i would guess the same methods applied to getting the icons and resources ?